# Command line video renderer: Nokia 3310

Tags: command-line, 18.04, video, video-conversion

I have a Nokia 3310 and it has a video player. Unfortunately, it has to have videos specially rendered for it at very low resolution and with very specific codecs. (MPEG-4 video)

I was wondering if there was any command line tool that could do this effectively. Because manually using Pitivi is a pain when working on large numbers of videos.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I'll try it out later tonight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) (installable from Ubuntu Software Store or via apt) is a GUI tool but you can queue up a load of files and then just let it do it's thing.

Or [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) command line tool.

Comment: Thanks a million bud! For future referance, the command to render to the Nokia 3310's specs is:
ffmpeg -i [input] -s 640x480 -vcodec mpeg4 [output].mp4

Comment: @GreatCanadianMoose Just for curiosity does the following work for your phone: `ffmpeg -i [input] -vf scale=640:-2 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -profile:v main -crf 24 -c:a aac -b:a 96k [output].mp4` ?

Comment: @andrew.46 Nah, the terminal spits out an error: ```[libx264 @ 0x5589f8c71ce0] Error setting profile main.
[libx264 @ 0x5589f8c71ce0] Possible profiles: baseline main high high10 high422 high444
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: @GreatCanadianMoose Hmmm... last go at it: `ffmpeg -i [input] -vf scale=640:-2 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 24 -c:a aac -b:a 96k [output].mp4`

Comment: @andrew.46 The rendering worked that time! I am sorry to let you know, it doesn't actually run on the Nokia 3310 Video Player. It doesn't run on the ACC codec, and trial and error suggests that it only supports MPEG-4. I made a poor quality youtube video a year or so ago which I can link if you are curious. I plan to make an updated version with better presentation this year with this program in mind. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GreatCanadianMoose I am a little curious :). Good to hear you have successfully used FFmpeg with your phone too!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121132/discussion-between-great-canadian-moose-and-andrew-46).